# Add colored border to some elements of table

Tags: 2013, formatting, datatable

I would like to know if it is possible to add a border of a specific color in a table.  The preset styles do not work as I keep some of the table boxes clear, and some colored and only want the border lines on the colored boxes.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you trying to format a list/library view, or a table in a web part, or something else?

Comment: You can make use of JSLink to customize the rendering of table. e.g. for item with string "urgent" change the div element wrapping it with red color. [Here is a tutorial](http://apprize.info/html5/sharepoint/5.html) and you can find a lot more in this forum and on Internet.